# Python: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Pitch' referenced before assignment" is there any way to fix this?

```
import winsound, random

Pitch = random.randint(1000, 10000)
Duration = random.randint(100, 500)

def random():
    winsound.Beep(Pitch, Duration)
    Pitch = random.randint(1000, 10000)
    Duration = random.randint(100, 500)
    winsound.Beep(Pitch, Duration)
    Pitch = random.randint(1000, 10000)
    Duration = random.randint(100, 500)
    winsound.Beep(Pitch, Duration)
    Pitch = random.randint(1000, 10000)
    Duration = random.randint(100, 500)
    winsound.Beep(Pitch, Duration)
    Pitch = random.randint(1000, 10000)
    Duration = random.randint(100, 500)
    winsound.Beep(Pitch, Duration)

random()
```

Comment: You need to mark them as global: `global Pitch, Duration`. Also, don't name your function `random` if you're importing the module `random`!

Comment: Just delete the ones at global scope.  Looks like they aren't used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `global`:

```
def random():
    global Pitch, Duration
    ...
```

But also please have a look that you re-define module `random` with the function `random()`.

Please rename the function to, well, `random_func()`

You can also use loops:

```
import winsound, random

def rand_func():
    for _ in range(5):
        Pitch = random.randint(1000, 10000)
        Duration = random.randint(100, 500)
        winsound.Beep(Pitch, Duration)

rand_func()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Pitch` and `Duration` variables in the `winsound.Beep(Pitch, Duration)` line have not been defined yet. They're distinct from the variables of the same name in the global scope.

In order to inform the interpreter that your `Pitch` and `Duration` variables are the same as those defined in the global scope, you need to use the `global` keyword in your function:

```
def random():
    global Pitch, Duration    # <<--- this resolves your scoping issue
    winsound.Beep(Pitch, Duration)
    Pitch = random.randint(1000, 10000)
```

Also, you should *defintely* rename your function and avoid naming your functions with the same names as those in the Python library.